# Celery: dynamic queue

Tags: python, celery

I'm writing a webhook processor for one Shopify app. The app has many shops installed that generate webhooks. I also have a microservice that consumes those webhooks and processes them as celery tasks. But the problem is because of Shopify API limits, and I can't run incoming webhooks for one shop concurrently.
I'm trying to get a flow like this:

- Got the webhook
- Checking if any worker is already processing a webhook for this shop
- a. If yes, put the task in the queue with the shop name, and make it wait until the previous task ends
- b. If no, create a new queue with the shop name and start executing the task on any worker available
- After completing all tasks in the queue - delete it

Maybe it's not the best solution and you can give me a better one.
The basic idea - run tasks with the same shop name (or tag) one by one and prevent other workers to take tasks from the queue. But it should run tasks for different shops (tags) concurrently.

Thanks,
Vitaly.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. Not so familiar with Celery, but queue management looking pretty limited... How about to [inspect currently running tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html) on new task and if task with current `shop_id` already exists re-`apply_async` same task [with delay](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown)?

Comment: @rzlvmp, I think to delay is not a good idea, because I don't know when the previous task will finish. Also, I need to prevent other workers take tasks with the same `shop_id` from the queue.

Comment: For example if your task length is 1 minute, You may set delay time to 5 secs. In other words your workers will check current task every 5 seconds and recreate new same one before previous task is running. `Also, I need to prevent other workers take tasks with the same` → Why? It is not matter which worker take a task and re-`apply_async` it again. Of course if you don't have separate roles for different workers.

Comment: It will work if you have only one pending task. But it can be more of them. For example, if one task runs and comes several after it. If apply_async with the same timeout you will lose the order.

Comment: @VitalyRadchik what Shopify webhook are you listening for?

Comment: @jjdoherty there are a lot of them, but generally most used is product/update. The problem is also that in my processing I make API calls that will cause more such webhooks to come. That is why I need to put them in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve the problem by having a distributed lock per shop. More about it here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

Comment: Thanks, I saw this. But this solution drops a new task if some worker is already running it. But I need to enqueue it in the order that tasks come. And make sure it will be executed only after the previous task is completed.